# How does mongoose.connect(connectionSring) work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I come from a python background when connecting to databases and executing sql without an ORM.  Say with the python library `cx_Oracle`, like so:

```
>>> conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connectionString)
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> _ = curs.execute(...)
```

More specifically, directing all of my calls to the database through the returned connection object `conn`, not the library `cx_Oracle` itself.

In an `express` app, using mongodb with `node.js` and `mongoose`, we might be doing something like:

```
require('./models/user'); // Defines new Schema in mongoose named 'users'
require('./services/passport');  // receives data from OAuth flow
// and writes new authenticated users to MongoDB database

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true});

const app = express();
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);  // handle OAuth routes and pass to passport authentication

// server runs and listens to routes etc
```

It seems like the imported library `mongoose` itself is getting set with new properties from:

```
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

As subsequent calls like the below in `./services/passport.js` to create new users have no obvious reference to our connection.

```
const User = mongoose.model('users');

// within an OAuth callback
new User({ id: response.data.id })
  .save()
  .then(...)
```

I've looked at the source for `Mongoose.prototype.connect` to understand this but am confused by the return statement.  After the promise is completed, it returns an arrow function with `_mongoose`, our instance of the prototype `Mongoose` itself with a new connection, yet we are not returning anything in our app.

```
Mongoose.prototype.connect = function() {
  const _mongoose = this instanceof Mongoose ? this : mongoose;
  const conn = _mongoose.connection;
  return conn.openUri(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]).then(() => _mongoose);
};
```

Can someone please explain what is happening to our imported `mongoose` library when we call `mongoose.connect(...)`?  Or perhaps send some resources so I can see a simple example of this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose will try to connect with the MongoClient internally and return the instance of mongoose.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(uri, options);
    _this.client = client;
    client.connect(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        _this.readyState = STATES.disconnected;
        return reject(error);
      }

      const db = dbName != null ? client.db(dbName) : client.db();
      _this.db = db;

}
```

this is the internal process of "conn.openUri" function and mongoose will execute the function. you can also connect the mongoClient directly without using mongoose.

```
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html
```